# How to get the values from a multiselect field which is an entity reference to a taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-8

I have a field in a content type which is an entity reference to a taxonomy and is mutiselect. How do I access the the values 
selected in a node? I am writing a form alter to add custom submit function for this I want the value in custom submit function

I tried using getFieldDefinition but not working at all. 
$node_details->field_adapt_language->target_id is giving me only the first value.

Answer (score 1):

Do a for each on it.

As It has been described on [Drupal Entity cheat sheet](https://www.yuseferi.com/en/blog/Drupal-entity-API-cheat-sheet) you can get all of them by the following snippet

```
$terms = [];
foreach ($node_details->field_adapt_language as $reference) {
  $terms []  =  $reference->target_id;   
}
```